# Dash plotly set custom folder as my assets folder

Tags: plotly-dash

I've built a dash dashboard and customised the appearance using my own css. The structure of the app is below

[image: Folder structure]

I then dockerised and deployed the dashboard our linux servers. Unfortunately our linux servers have overwrriten the assets folder with it's own css.

In order the app to find it's own CSS, I need to specify my own assets folder in the dash app.

I've tried various syntax locally(below) but can't get it work

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,static_folder='/new_assets/')
app = dash.Dash(__name__,assets_folder='/new_asssets/')
app = dash.Dash(__name__,assets_url_path='/new_asssets/')
```

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Turn out this was the right way to do it, but you need to specify the absolute path so I added this line to the top of my code and running the code from the dashboard directory.

```
import os
assets_path = os.getcwd() +'/src/new_assets'
app = dash.Dash(__name__,assets_folder=assets_path)
```

Comment: Relative paths also seem to work. Leaving off the leading slash, `foo`, is the same as `./foo`. Starting with a `/` implies an absolute path.